# Resolve promise inside method when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, dom

I have a 'slideshow' of sorts made of popups in a vue.js template, where each slide is a separate component and the parent component calls each slide in a 'for' loop. Users move from one slide to the other by clicking on a button inside the component. The way I currently have it set up, when the parent calls the 'activates' a slide through `this.$refs` it toggles a class to make the slide visible, then creates a listener inside of a promise, resolving that promise only when the listener is activated. I'm sure that there is a better way to do this, as it feels like my code breaks some unwritten rules of Javascript by defining a listener inside of a Promise. However, I cannot think of a better way as I am a relative newcomer to JS and Vue. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

The component is called an 'Instruction', as I'm using them to explain different parts of my application.

Button to move slide: `<button v-on:submit.prevent name="button-text" :id="'next-instruction-button-'+index">Next</button>`

Code in `Instruction` component that is used to activate and deactivate the content:

```
handleClick() {
    return new Promise(res => {
        var popup = document.getElementById(`myPopup-${this.index}`);
        popup.classList.toggle("show");

        /* Not totally sure what I've built here, but it works */
        new Promise(resolve => {
            document.querySelector(`#next-instruction-button-${this.index}`).addEventListener('click', () => {
                return resolve();
            })
        })
        .then(() => {
            popup.classList.toggle("show");
            res();
        })
    })
},
```

Calling from parent function:

```
async showInstructions() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= this.numInstructions; i++) {
        console.log(i)
        await this.$refs[`instruction-${i}`].handleClick();
    }
},
```

The code for each of the slides is originally from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use `refs` and save Promise `resolve` function until user clicks button

```js
methods: {
  onClick() {
    this.resolve();
  },
  handleClick() {
    const popupRef = this.$refs.popupRef;
    const classList = popupRef.classList;
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        classList.toggle("show");
        this.resolve = resolve;
    })
    .then(() => {
       classList .toggle("show");
    })
  })
},
```

**Example**

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.component("child-component", {
  props: {
    text: String,
    response: String,
    clicked: Boolean
  },
  template: `<div class="instruction">
    <div>{{text}}</div>
    <span ref="popupRef" class="popup">Click it!</span>
    <button v-if="!clicked" @click="onClick">Ok Done!</button>
    <div v-if="clicked">{{response}}</div>
  </div>`,
  methods: {
    onClick() {
      this.resolve();
    },
    handleClick() {
      const popupRef = this.$refs.popupRef;
      const classList = popupRef.classList;
      
      return new Promise(resolve => {
          classList.toggle("show");
          this.resolve = resolve;
        })
        .then(() => {
          classList.toggle("show");
        })
    },
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#container',
  data() {
    return {
      text: 'Show Instructions',
      disabled: false,
      instructions: [{
          id: 1,
          text: 'Eat something!',
          response: 'Nice!',
          clicked: false
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          text: 'Work',
          response: 'Wow!',
          clicked: false
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async showInstructions() {
      this.disabled = true;
      this.text = "Showing instructions...";
      
      const combined = this.instructions.map((obj, index) => [
        obj,
        this.$refs.instructions[index]
      ]);
      
      for (let [instruction, ref] of combined) {
        await ref.handleClick();
        this.$set(instruction, 'clicked', true);
      }
      
      this.text = 'Processing...';
      
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.disabled = false;
        this.text = 'Show Instructions';
      
        this.instructions = this.instructions.map(instruction => ({
          ...instruction,
          clicked: false
        }))
      }, 500);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.instruction {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.popup {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: 90px;
  
}

.popup.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <child-component ref="instructions" :key="item.id" v-bind="item" v-for="item in instructions"></child-component>
  <button :disabled="disabled" @click="showInstructions">{{text}}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I ask why you think that would be a better option?

Comment: You are not accessing DOM directly. Additionally you can get rid of `popupRef ` variable and use class binding